# Removing tablespace references from database scripts

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am relatively new to SQL and only dabble with it when it is required. I have done some research on this but have limited success. I need to remove the tablespace references from the code. The settings already exist in the database for a default tablespace. By the way it is an Oracle database.

If I have these lines of code:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE RAND_CATEGORY(
-------- insert random vars ---------------
CONSTRAINT RAND_CATEGORY PRIMARY KEY(cat_id,ver_num)
USING INDEX TABLESPACE VG_NDX ENABLE
)TABLESPACE VG_DATA';
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE RAND_CATEGORY(
-------- insert random vars ---------------
CONSTRAINT RAND_CATEGORY PRIMARY KEY(cat_id,ver_num)
USING INDEX TABLESPACE VG_NDX ENABLE
)';
```

My question is, should I remove the entire line:

```
USING INDEX TABLESPACE VG_NDX ENABLE
```

Or should I just remove the "TABLESPACE VG_NDX" and leave it as:

```
USING INDEX ENABLE
```

Keep in mind that I am new to this and I just need help with this. I have been learning SQL for the past 2 weeks and tablespaces are a bit funky to me. Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `USING INDEX` clause allow to have more control over the constraint associated index creation, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes003.htm.
In your case the `TABLESPACE` storage clause.

If you want to let Oracle use the default tablespace you can remove the `USING INDEX` clause entirely leaving `ENABLE`.

Although in a `CREATE TABLE` a primary key constraint associated index is automatically enabled (unless I missed something) so I can't see any point of keeping the `ENABLE`.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up asking our DBA and he said to take everything out but leave ENABLE. I'm not sure of the reason. It's possible that it's already enabled by default but perhaps they just want to make it easier for the programmer to understand what's going on. I'm not really sure of the reasoning. 

So I changed
    USING INDEX TABLESPACE VG_NDX ENABLE
    'To
    ENABLE

Comment: `ENABLE` is not part of `USING INDEX`. Both `ENABLE` and `USING INDEX` are part of `constraint_state` shown at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/clauses002.htm#CJADJGEC. Looking at the railroad diagram for `constraint_state` one can see that the `ENABLE` option for the constraint stands alone. `using_index_clause` allows customization of the index created or used by the constraint. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/clauses002.htm#CJAGEBIG

Comment: @minhaz1 : You shoudln't accept answer that are not correct~
@ShannonSeverance : thanks for the correction, although I still don't see the point of keeping `ENABLE`. I couldn't find it in the documentation but testing it show clearly that declaring a `PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT` inside a `CREATE TABLE` statement enable it by default. Either it's a database setting, or it's fixed, anyway why specify the `ENABLE` in this case ?

Comment: I edited the response to match reality, it should now be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Read this document:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7003.htm

It provides a good overview of what tablespaces are and should solve the issue.